# Native coin Price doesn’t show

Tags: blockchain, metamask

i was wondering what you need to do for the price to show up from the native coin of a layer 1 blockchain. The blockchain mainnetz is listed on coingecko and cmc for a while now but metamask is still not showing price. The support isn’t helpful either and send me to this platform. Hopefully someone can help me figure this out